# Make Eclipse use src/test/resources instead of src/main/resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, resources, properties

I'm writing a little Maven application in Eclipse. I store some property files and my application context in the directory src/main/resources.

I now want to make Eclipse use properties in the directory src/test/resources. So when I run and debug the program in Eclipse, these test properties should be used.

Do you know how I could make that happen?

Comment: It does so automatically. How are you reading them?

Comment: I read the property file in the application context xml with <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="db.properties" />
 </bean>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you use the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) or [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), `src/test/resources` precedes `src/main/resources` on the classpath (more precisely, their output directories). In other words, there is nothing to do, things just works as on the command line.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

1. Go to "Run->Run configurations..." (in case of debug "Run->Debug configurations...")
2. Open Run (Debug) configuration which you use
3. Open "Classpath" tab
4. Select "User Entries" and click "Advanced..." on the right
5. In the opened window select "Add folder", point to your src/test/resources
6. This folder will appear under "User entries", then you should move it up to make it the first on your classpath

Comment: src/main/resources goes before src/test/resources on the classpath. Therefore your db.properties from src/main/resources is loaded.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, it helped me alot! For me, the exact click path was (maybe newer version of eclipse?): Menu "Run" -> select "Run configurations ..." -> Select tab "Dependencies" -> select "Classpath entries" in the tree -> click button [Advanced ...] -> Select "Add Folders" from the radio group -> click button [Ok].

Comment: My use of the answer showed me, that I was indeed missing a folder in the build. But in the end it wasn't necessary to configure an extra folder. I had a typo when creating the "resources"-folder in the test folder so maven was not aware of my misnamed folder. When I had corrected the typo, maven could recognize the folder and I could use: context menu on the projekt -> "Maven" -> "Update project ..." and to be save:  menu "Project" -> "Clean ...". That was sufficient, even without an axtra folder configured in the Run configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Use a test override (e.g. testOverrides.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!--  this file need to be imported before other contexts to ensure the test properties take effect -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/testproperties/*.properties"/>

</beans>
```

In your tests, make sure it's imported first:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:META-INF/spring/testOverrides.xml","classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeTest { ... }
```

Now put all your test properties in `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/testproperties/`.

You have to also make sure that the `main` placeholder configurer doesn't ever see `testproperties`, e.g. here's mine:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
```

It doesn't use the double-* wildcard, so will only look at that one directory.

I use the above method with great success.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in eclipse 2021. Go to Run As Configuration (or debug) and go to Classpath tab. Now you could check or uncheck, depends if you want to use /src/main/resources or /src/test/resources, like so:

[image]

Finaly, apply and run your program