# Unable to get Maven (and Eclipse) to use test resources while testing

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven

I am having trouble getting unit tests to use resources provided under `src\test\resources` instead of those in `src\main\resources`.  Yes, the resource in question is named identically in both places.

I have done a fair amount of research, looked at StackOverflow posts such as:

- [Make Maven use test resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267312/how-to-make-maven-use-test-resources)
- [Make Eclipse use test resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912517/make-eclipse-use-src-test-resources-instead-of-src-main-resources)

However this basic issue has me stumped.

I have a very standard Maven Java project set up:

- Application source & resources under `src\main`
- Test source & resources under `src\test`

Eclipse (thanks to M2Eclipse plugin) has `src\main\java`, `src\main\resources`, `src\test\java` and `src\test\resources` all in its build path.

With this setup, when I run my unit test from within Eclipse resource files in `src\main\resources` are being referenced.  I can see why (because they are in the build path) but I don't know how to prevent it.  The unit test configuration panel does not allow me to tweak the order of (default) classpath components.

Even if I were to gloss over my inability to run my tests from Eclipse, Maven doesn't play nice either.  I can see that the `processResources` step is copying all the test resources to under the `target\test-classes` tree.  However when the unit test is executed the copy of the resource file under `target\classes` is being consulted.

Surely I am overlooking something *obvious*.  I appreciate any help you can provide.

[EDIT] **Adding more (possibly relevant information)**:

The resource file in question is a file named `persistence.xml`.  It is used by [Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) to connect to relational data sources.  The version of the file used by the application is placed in `src\main\resources\META-INF`.  A Maven build (of a WAR, say) places the `META-INF` directory under the `classes` directory.  Therefore EclipseLink tooling finds this file.

```
src/main
  |
  + -- java/com/company/ProductDao.java
  | 
  + -- resources/META-INF/persistence.xml  (Requires application container)
  |
src/test
  |
  + -- java/com/company/ProductDaoTest.java
  | 
  + -- resources/META-INF/persistence.xml  (out of container for unit tests)
  |
```

The takeaway here is: **EclipseLink requires a file called `persistence.xml` in a `META-INF` directory on the classpath** (yes, defaults can be overridden but let's not go there).

Therefore when the *unit test* runs the same application logic is invoked.  However the version of the file in `src\main\resources` cannot be used.  A *different version* is made available in the `src\test\resources` directory.

Since the version in `src\main\resources` is being used it *appears* that my only recourse is to instruct Eclipselink during unit testing to look for a different filename.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just create a new persistence-unit in your src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml that you can use during unit testing and `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` That seems to be what you'd be doing with two persistence.xml files anyways.

Comment: A different persistence unit (possibly) in the same file.  That's an interesting thought.  I need to figure out how to instruct the class to use a different persistence unit (PU).  After all the PU is identified via an annotation on the Java class and (in my case) is wired using Spring.  Thanks for the tip, I'll have to think it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Maven issue at the root of it. You'd have the exact same problem if you had everything collapsed into a single source folder. Think about what you are really doing. Your unit tests require the code from src/main or else it wouldn't be a unit test of that code. src/main/java and src/main/resources make up the artifact you are testing. You don't mix and match the directories for your unit test.

You are basically doing this:

```
/src/com/mycompany/myresource.txt        
/src/com/mycompany/MyAwesomeClass.java
/src/com/mycompany/myresource.txt
/src/com/mycompany/TestMyAwesomeClass.java
```

Don't do that. Configure your unit tests to load mock data / your resource file from another file.

I haven't had many, if any issues with Maven and Eclipse. Realize that Maven is not magic. And that if you are going to use Maven and Eclipse everything has to be driven by the POM file not the other way around. Then things work beautifully.

Just to reclarify, your issue has nothing to do with Maven. You are declaring a resource twice on the classpath. You need to rethink your unit tests. There are things you can do to get around this with Profiles but it's an abuse of the build system.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment of using the tools in concert ("everything has to be driven by the POM file") and not abusing the build system.  I am trying to play by the rules.  However it appears that the _tooling_ cannot be relied on to set the stage on which the tests are run.  It is *the tests themselves* that have to have the smarts to *know* which resource to use.  I welcome any suggestion you may have on how to configure unit tests to load one but not another identically named resource file.

Comment: @SriSankaran The problem isn't a Maven problem. You have two exact resources in two exact locations on the classpath. Without class loaders it's a bad design. Can you update your question with the specific Use Case you are trying to solve? I am certain there is a better solution that trying to put two of the exact same resources on the class path.

Comment: I am accepting this answer 'cos it explains the symptom.  There are few different "cures":  Make only one file available at test time, place all settings in one file and conditionally switch active one etc.  No matter what, the conditional switch must be in the build tooling or the configuration file _not in the source (or test) code_.

Answer (score 0):

I answered and then had to spent few moments trying to figure it out again. 
In the surefire documentation it says that test-classes should be first in classpath :
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

And surefire shows (with mvn --debug option):
[DEBUG] test classpath:
...\target\test-classes
...\target\classes
....m2\repository\javax\enterprise\cdi-api\1.2\cdi-api-1.2.jar
....m2\repository\javax\el\javax.el-api\3.0.0\javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar 
...
but stil it uses target\classes first. Strange this bug was reported some time ago.
Then whatever I do the persistence.xml from classes folder is taken first.

So I had to use two persistence units in one persistence.xml file what might be not the best but works fine also.